# Questionable Tournament Rule With Two Players Left

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, tournament

I have never heard this rule before but my cousin swore it is real:

When a Texas Hold Em Tournament is down to only two players, each player is dealt their first two cards. If one of the players goes All IN immediately after receiving the preflop and the 2nd player goes ALL IN as well, are no more cards flopped and the entire bet rides on who's two cards in hand are better?

I was always under the impression that the rest of the cards had to be flopped and the person with the best 5 card hand wins.

Comment: I do not get the downvote. Fundamental answer since the ruling is ridiculous, but for a novice I would understand this question if someone tells you this.

Answer (score 8):

This is false. The hand will play out as usual with the flop, turn, and river.

I'm not sure where your friend heard this or why he believed it. There are plenty of televised heads-up tournament matches available with a quick youtube search where you can see how heads-up hands get played.

Comment: I already knew the answer to the question, however, I wanted someone outside of our circle who knows the answer to prove the point. Thank you for the quick response.